# Promises to async/await in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, async-await, es6-promise

I use visual studio code and in those articles:

=> https://dev.to/ben/visual-studio-code-can-now-convert-your-long-chains-of-promisethens-into-asyncawait-automagically-1b1b

=> https://umaar.com/dev-tips/182-typescript-async-await/

=>https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28

they say there is a feature which is vscode can convert promises to async await itself but I couldn't make it for my .js files. Can you help me?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know it but i just tried in my vscode. When you just click or double click your function, a light bulb appears like in the videos you copied. Then you click on it and click "convert to async..."

- You need to have javascript.validate.enable set true (vscode -> Preferences -> Settings) (or cmd-, in OSX).
- I have version 1.30.0 (1.30.0). Check your version.
- If none of this works maybe there is something wrong with your Promise. Try these examples...

TS:

```
function example(): Promise<boolean> {
  return fetch('https://stackoverflow.com').then( result => result.ok; );
}
```

JS:

```
function example() 
{ 
  return Promise.resolve(1) 
    .then((value) => { 
      console.log(value) 
    }) 
    .catch(err => { 
      console.log(err); 
    })
}
```

Comment: My file is javascript vscode's this feature needs typescript?

Comment: No. I tried now with this code:

`function example() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value)
    return Promise.reject(2)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}`

Try if it works. If it works maybe you can copy the code you're using.

Also make sure you have your Language Mode as javascript in the right bottom corner of vscode.

Comment: Yeah, you right it works for me too... My file is too big maybe this is a problem with my file.

Comment: same issue here. It feels like VSC can only convert small piece of code from promise to async/await. For large and more complex code, you probably have to do it yourself.